# Symfony: prevent form field from being saved

Tags: forms, symfony1

I have a form to change email, `EmailChangeForm` which extends the guard user form, `sfGuardUserForm` and uses two columns: `email_address` and `password`.

I want the form to check if the password is correct and if so, change the email to the new one.

My problem is that the form also saves the `password` field to the user object.

I know that since the password is checked, it cannot be changed in theory, but I still don't like it being re-saved with the new value from the form, so is there a way to make the form only save the `email_address` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a sceleton like this :

```
class emailForm extends sfFrom {
    public function configure(){
       $this->widgetSchema['email'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText();
       $this->widgetSchema['password'] = new sfWidgetFormInputPassword();
       $this->validatorSchema['password'] = new myValidatorPassword();
    }
}

class myValidatorPassword extends sfValidatorBase{
    protected function doClean($value)
    {
        $clean = (string) $value;

        // current user
        $sf_guard_user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser();
        if($sf_guard_user)
        {
            // password is ok?
            if ($sf_guard_user->checkPassword($value))
            {
                return $clean;
            }
        }
        // Throw error
        throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'invalid', array('value' => $value)); 
    }
}
```

So in your action you can easily save the new password :

```
/***** snip *****/
if($this->form->isValid()){
    // set and save new password to current user
    $user = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser();
    $user->setPassword($formValues["password"]);
    $user->save();
/***** snip *****/
```

Of course this is a basic approach, improvements are always welcome :-)

Comment: Ups sorry, `$user->setEmail($formValues["email"]` will do the trick. As plus you have the password validator reuseable !

Comment: yep, it'll work :) I've also came up with the solution of modifying the `doSave()` method of the form, for those who want more symfony-way solution

Answer (score 0):

create the new form (`editUserForm` for example) that extend the base form and then unset the password by this code

```
class editUserForm extend baseForm{
   public function configure(){
      unset($this['password']);
   }
 }
```

all the name above is an example you must change it to your name.

Comment: but then i cant add a validator for the password

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you're using the `useFields` function in your `EmailChangeForm` class. With that you can define which fields you want to edit with your form (this is better than `unset` because if you add more fields you dont have to worry with `useFields`). Example:

```
$this->useFields(array( 
  'email'
));
```

DO NOT INCLUDE THE PASSWORD!

Second: In your template put an extra input field for your password with the same name schema (updatemail[password]).

Third: In your action before the `$form->isValid` method you add the following:

```
$params = $request->getParameter($form->getName();
unset($params['password'];
$form->bind($params), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
if($form->isValid()) {...}
```

Comment: how can i check if the password is correct if i'm unsetting it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there is only one field in EmailChangeForm, and that EmailChangeForm extends SfUserForm...

To eliminate all the fields except the email field add this to the configure method:

$this->useFields(array('email'));